# Index time field level boosting in Lucene 6.6.0?

Tags: lucene, scoring, lucene-boosting

In Lucene 6.6.0 and greater, Field level index time boosting is [deprecated](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#setBoost-float-). The documentation states:

> Index-time boosts are deprecated, please index index-time scoring
>   factors into a doc value field and combine them with the score at
>   query time using eg. FunctionScoreQuery.

Previously one would boost a field at index time like so:

```
    Field title = new Field(PaperDAO.LUCENE_FIELD_TITLE, titleStr, fieldType);
    title.setBoost(3.00f);
    document.add(title);

    Field authors = new Field(PaperDAO.LUCENE_FIELD_AUTHOR, StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(this.getAuthorsForLucene()), fieldType);
    authors.setBoost(10.00f);
    document.add(authors);
```

I do not understand how the suggested FunctionScoreQuery is an appropriate replacement for field level boosting, as one constructs a FunctionScoreQuery given only an existing Query and a DoubleValuesSource representing the boost value for only one of potentially many fields:

```
// INDEX TIME
Field title = new Field(PaperDAO.LUCENE_FIELD_TITLE, titleStr, fieldType);
document.add(title);
document.add(new FloatDocValuesField(PaperDAO.LUCENE_FIELD_TITLE + "_boost", 3.00f));

// QUERY TIME
new FunctionScoreQuery(query, DoubleValuesSource.fromFloatField(PaperDAO.LUCENE_FIELD_TITLE + "_boost"))
```

Can someone please explain the appropriate replacement for Field#setBoost @ index time in Lucene >= 6.6.0? Are we supposed to be enumerating all possible fields at query time and applying the relevant boost? If so, how is that query constructed?

Comment: Looks like there's no simple answer to that simple question. Do you have a solution meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you still have some time to use old-style index time boosts, since they only will be remove in **Lucene 7.0** :)

Moving on to the subject, community long time ago [decided](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6818?focusedCommentId=14934801&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14934801), that index-time boost is a complex and hard to get it right technique.

What I think is the current idea - is not to replace per-field index time boost with per field docvalues field, but rather replace all index time boosts for a document with 1 accumulated score in the docvalues field and later use it during search.

> please index index-time scoring **factors** into a doc value **field**
>   and combine them with the score at query time

The quote is from the [javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html), which only strengthen me in this idea. You could index multiple factors into just one field.

The open question to me is - how to combine several factors into 1. I hope that's something to test and validate (to use multiplication, sum or some linear combination)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to boost different fields using FunctionScoreQuery, the suggested method is the following (taken from [CustomeScoreProvider](http://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_1/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/CustomScoreQuery.html)):

> For more complex custom scores, use the lucene-expressions library
>
> ```
>    SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
>    bindings.add("score", DoubleValuesSource.SCORES);
>    bindings.add("boost1", DoubleValuesSource.fromIntField("myboostfield"));
>    bindings.add("boost2", DoubleValuesSource.fromIntField("myotherboostfield"));
>    Expression expr = JavascriptCompiler.compile("score * (boost1 + ln(boost2))");
>    FunctionScoreQuery q = new FunctionScoreQuery(inputQuery, expr.getDoubleValuesSource(bindings));
> ```